# How to add library to Processing?

Tags: java, processing, jcodec

i would like to use jar library from http://jcodec.org/ with Processing. I know there are many of tutorials about libraries but none of them are clear enough for me to understand. I have already dragged and dropped the *jcodec-0.1.5.jar* to my sketch window and it created a folder named `"code"` with the file *jcodec-0.1.5.jar* in it, but when i want to use

```
FrameGrab grab = new FrameGrab(new File("filename.mp4"));
```

Im still getting

> "The Constructor FrameGrab(file) is not defined."

Do i have to import something ? 
if so what to i have to type after "import" ? any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: move the jar into the lib/ folder of the project

Comment: the class FrameGrab (or any other classes from jcodec) will not be available until you import the correct package. do you have a line like `import org.jcodec.api.*` in your code?

Comment: thanks for reply, i followed your instruction and it added import org.jcodec.api.*; but i still get FrameGrab not defined.

Comment: @distiking have you moved the jar to the lib/ folder?

Answer (score 0):

The class you are trying to instantiate does not have a constructor defined that matches the constructor you are calling. There is no constructor that accepts `File` as an argument. 
 
Try calling the default constructor:
`FrameGrab grab = new FrameGrab();`

Comment: thanks for your help, but now im getting "The constructor FrameGrab() is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help, the library is working. When i just type FrameGrab grab; without defining it the program runs fine, so it must be the constructor which i will figure out later. Thanks